# Problems on iOS (Objective-C) playing AAC files in AudioQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, audioqueue, audioqueueservices

this is my first post here, I hope you can help me with this. I'm working on this code to get an AAC playback based on AudioQueue, I tested this with WAV format, and it works. The thing happens when I put either a .CAF or .M4A file and then I trigger the play method, this error comes up:

> ERROR:     >aq> 1608: failed (-66674); will stop (66150/0 frames)

I've been searching for this error code -66674 on Apple's Dev support documents and says that I have an error involving a problem with AudioQueuePrime or AudioQueueStart (right now AudioQueuePrime is not on the code, but I've been testing this also). I know that it's possible to use AAC w/AudioQueues, and in my case I believe this is the most reliable way to sync sounds accurately.

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    //OSStatus result;
    NSArray *audioTracks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"/Users/mauro_ptt/Documents/XCODE/SimpleAQPlayViewController/Sample01.caf",
                            nil];

    for (id object in audioTracks) {
    // Open the audio file from an existing NSString path
    NSURL *sndFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:object];

    AudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)sndFileURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &mAudioFile);

    // get audio format
    UInt32 dataFormatSize = sizeof(mDataFormat);
    AudioFileGetProperty(mAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat, &dataFormatSize, &mDataFormat);

    // create playback queue
    AudioQueueNewOutput(&mDataFormat, AQOutputCallback, (__bridge void *)(self), CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &mQueue);

    // get buffer size, number of packets to read
    UInt32 maxPacketSize;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(maxPacketSize);
    // get the theoretical max packet size without scanning the entire file
    AudioFileGetProperty(mAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyPacketSizeUpperBound, &propertySize, &maxPacketSize);
    // get sizes for up to 0.5 seconds of audio
    DeriveBufferSize(mDataFormat, maxPacketSize, 0.5, &bufferByteSize, &mNumPacketsToRead);

    // allocate packet descriptions array
    bool isFormatVBR = (mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket == 0 || mDataFormat.mFramesPerPacket == 0);
    if (isFormatVBR) {
        mPacketsDescs = (AudioStreamPacketDescription*) malloc(mNumPacketsToRead * sizeof(AudioStreamPacketDescription));
    } else {
        mPacketsDescs = NULL;
    }

    // Get magic cookie (COMPRESSED AAC)
    UInt32 cookieSize = sizeof(UInt32);
    OSStatus couldNotGetProperty = AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(mAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, &cookieSize, NULL);
    if ((couldNotGetProperty == noErr) && cookieSize) {
        char *magicCookie = (char *) malloc(cookieSize);
        AudioFileGetProperty(mAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, &cookieSize, magicCookie);
        AudioQueueSetProperty(mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie, magicCookie, cookieSize);
        free(magicCookie);
    }

    // Allocate and prime audio queue buffers
    mCurrentPacket = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < kNumberBuffers; ++i) {
        AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(mQueue, bufferByteSize, &mBuffers[i]);
        AQOutputCallback((__bridge void *)(self), mQueue, mBuffers[i]);
    }
        mIsRunning = true;
    AudioQueueStart(mQueue, NULL);

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you implement `AQOutputCallback`?

Comment: I've just solved it. It was a problem regarding AQOutputCallback putting an object instead of a struct, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a problem regarding AQOutputCallback, must be careful on placing the right types on each function arguments.

Comment: I am developing a remote desktop application, rendering video and audio and sending data separately trying to sync using Audio Queue Services, achieved the result too, but it gave glitches in sound, used AudioQueueReset for syncing sound with video but getting glitches.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a month ago and I couldn’t figured it out. So ended up using .wav. The size was bigger but luckily I only had to play 5 files.